How to Access Candidate Data Using Indeed API?
I am currently exploring options to access candidate data for a job opening through the Indeed API. I have checked the Indeed API documentation (https://developer.indeed.com/) but couldn't find a direct method to retrieve candidate information.
Has anyone encountered a similar need and found a workaround or alternative solution? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I attempted to access candidate data through the Indeed API by reviewing the documentation and exploring available endpoints. I expected to find a specific endpoint or method dedicated to retrieving candidate information. However, upon examining the documentation, I couldn't locate any direct means to access candidate data. As a result, I'm seeking guidance from others who may have encountered this issue and found a workaround or alternative solution.

This question is similar to: Get candidate using Indeed API. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
